# Figurative expression "Это в его духе"

Tags: грамматика, словоупотребление, притяжательные-местоимения

> Это в **его** духе. / Это в **её** духе. / Это в **их** духе.

I assume this is a figurative expression with the meaning of "it sounds like him/her/them".

> (**в** = followed by the prepositional case)
>
> (**его**/**её**/**их** = genitive case)
>
> (**духе** = prepositional singular case)

My question is:

1. "их" is plural, so shouldn't you say "Это в их **духах**" with the prepositional plural case instead?
2. Why is it incorrect to say "Это в **тебя** духе" оr "Это в **вас** духе" to mean "that sounds like you"? Even though they share the same construction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это в **моем,твоем, его, её, нашем, вашем, их** духе.

It's an idiom. Meaning

It's **my, your, his, her, our, their** manner/way.

Since it's an idiom, the noun духе doesn't change, but it has a possessive pronoun. Меня, тебя aren't possessive pronouns, so you cannot use them.

Comment: Hi. I initially thought that "его" in "Это в его духе" was the Genitive of Personal pronoun, but is this "его" actually the masculine Prepositional case of the Possessive pronoun?

Comment: Correct. And I saw that your confusion came from the similarity of different pronouns "his"and "him",  because in Russian they are both "его".

Answer (score 2):

1. It's incorrect because `их` isn't a demonstrative pronoun for `дух`, but a possessive pronoun of people to whom `дух` belongs so to speak. It's also incorrect because `в smbd's духе`, where `дух` is in singular form, is a fixed idiom.

Literally

> Это в их духе - This is in their spirit

2. It's incorrect because the idiom requires possessive pronoun for `дух`, while `тебя`, `вас` etc. are inflected personal pronouns.

Possessive pronouns of the 3d person `их/его/её` (their/his/her) derive from Genitive of personal pronouns `они/он/она`, but as all other possessive pronouns answer the question `чей?` and not `кого?` and *grammatically are similar to adjectives* except that unlike the rest of them these 3 don't inflect to match the case of the noun they describe.

Thus `в духе` (чьём?) `их/его/вашем`.

Comment: Hi. I was under the impression that ***Possessive pronouns*** and ***Genitive of personal pronouns*** are one and the same, but are they actually different things? I was referring to the declension table here: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D1%8B#Russian

Comment: that's a table for personal pronouns (which they should have clearly stated) and as i mentioned only 3d person possessive pronouns derive from Genitive of their personal counterparts, which is reflected in the [table](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Russian_pronouns), where `я` for instance in Genitive is inflected as `меня` whereas possessive from `я` is `мой` and possessive Genitive is `моего`

Comment: [here's a table of possessive pronouns](https://www.ruspeach.com/learning/3371/)